# how to import a function from another file in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have been asked to do testing in swift and I have no idea about swift

So, I was just reviewing the code and trying to make sense out of it.

I was in a file say `xyzTests.swift` where we wrote all the test case.

By going through the test cases written in the code, the first thing was something like this

```
func xyz() {
        var failureMessage: String? = nil;
        startSess(validity: 3)
}
```

In Javascript,one can only do something like this if

1. There is a function declared anywhere in the same file
2. if we are importing it from somewhere

So I searched in my file to find function declaration from `startSess` but wasn't able to find it. Then I clicked on jump to definition and found it some other file named `utils.swift`

```
internal func startSess(validity: Int = 1) {
}
```

I checked the file if there was at-least a reference of an import for at-least util but can't find any.

These are all the import statements in my code

```
import Foundation

@testable import session
```

Can someone explain me how we can use `startSess`?

Comment: so , function `xyz()` and `startSess` are in different Swift files right ??

Comment: @NayanDave Yap. There is a parent root folder `tests`. tests contains a file `xyzTests.swift` and `utils.swift`. `utils.swift` contains `startSess` which is being called in a function `xyz` which is inside `xyzTests.swift`

Comment: okay , so you just want to know `how to call a function from another file` , right???

Comment: @NayanDave Yap. That's correct

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the right site for basic language training, you need to pick up a book and learn the basics yourself. [Here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) is an excellent online book.

Answer (score 2):

**See, There are various different methods to call a function from another file Some of them are as given below**
(and Pardon me if I left any methods in this answer, I am open to edits :) )

1. As @Vollan said , importing the whole workspace , so you can access any function from any file anywhere in the project
2. Calling or Loading the file (in your case `util.swift`) and using the function in another file(`xyz.swift`)
   ex: In `xyz.swift`,

   ```
   func xyz() {
       let a = util() //Loading the swiftfile
       a.startSess(validity: 3) //using the function of swiftfile
   }
   ```
3. making that function `global` which you want to use.

   ```
   extension UIViewController { //In most cases UIViewController is used in all files so extending it helps
       func startSess(validity: Int = 1) {
       }
   }
   ```
4. You can directly make that function global even if you are not using any extensions or any classes by using `Foundation`(As in any file `Foundation` is must imported in the `Header` of any `SwiftFile`)

Ex: - Make any `SwiftFile` say named `abc.swift` and in that file

```
import Foundation
func startSess(validity: Int = 1) {
    //Your Code
}
```

***Now, you can call this function by `startSess(param)` in any file in your whole project.***

Comment: Pretty sure you can't use the classes or extensions of the workspace if you havn't given access to the workspace by importing it?

Comment: I've edited my answer, hope it's more correct now :)

Comment: It's still only reachable within it's target membership look at it like this: the Test membership is your project and the startSess function is within Alamofire. You can't call the function in Alamofire wiitthout actually importing Alamofire. Hence, you have to import your main workspace.

Comment: What you are saying is correct. If his goal was to just randomly call another function within the same target membership. Which kinda is  the title of the question. But in his description it's a function call  between the test and live environment.

Comment: Thanks @Vollan , you know more as your are senior and I really appreciate that , but that's why I asked him in comment before answering if he just wants to know `how to call a function from another file` and he agreed ...then I answered accordingly the `file` criteria... :)

Answer (score 1):

I take it that the `startSess` is a function that is outside of  any class then as it's being called in that way?

what `@testable import session` does is importing your entire workspace to be reachable from your test class. If you look in the right tab of the test file you can see that the target membership is only selected for tests (as it should be). And therefor it can't reach the rest of your code without the `@testable import`

Comment: Vollan, In the right tab, under tag inspector I see target membership to be the folder `tests` . which is the root folder so I can use `startSess` in all the files inside folder `tests`. Also, then if I create a function in another file with name `startSess` what will happen? will it throw an error?

Comment: If you create function with same name in some file, then at calling time in that file only , you need to use 'self.startSess(param)` , is you just use 'startSess(param)` then it won't show error but you won't get desired output

Comment: That looks weird so say there are two files `util1.xyz` and `util2.xyz` and both have function `startSess` so If I call `startSess` in `xyzTests.swift` inside function `test`. it won't throw an error and can execute either one of them? Shouldn't it at-least warn you about this?

Comment: no, when you will start to write `startSess` to call , it will ask you to choose between two available function in two different files , so you already know which `startSess` you're calling....that's why it doesn't show error

Comment: @NayanDave The way `startSess` is being called is because it is outside an class hence no class reference in hisi code. If he were to create another function witih the same name, there are a requirement that the 2 functions have different params, or he will get an error. And after that he can choose whether he want `startSess` with params setup 1 or params setup 2

Comment: oh...yes, I keep forgetting that part, thanks for keep enlightening again and again...can you share your twitter or any id ,so I can get in touch if you don't mind ?

Comment: @Vollan, it keeps showing me error that 'mail address can't be found or unable to receive mail.'

Comment: it is exactly the same

Comment: give me yours then